"extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error message
The latex code shown below is not running for me.

Error : Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

\begin{equation}\nonumber
{\small     
G=\begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{\phi X_{1}X_{3}} & -\sqrt{kX_{2}} & 0 & -\sqrt{bX_{4}X_{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & \sqrt{\alpha X_2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{\beta X_2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\delta} & \sqrt{\delta} & 0 & -\sqrt{\mu X_{3}} & 0 & 0\\
        -\sqrt{\phi X_{1}X_{3}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{\gamma X_{1}X_{3}^{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\xi X_{4}} & -\sqrt{rX_{1}}
\end{pmatrix} 
}
\end{equation}


Welcome to TeX.SE. This question is similar to: How to use more than 10 tab stops in bmatrix or other amsmath matrix environments?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In addition to needing to provide a directive such as \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{11} before the \begin{equation} statement in question, you should also note that \small is a text-mode command that shouldn't be placed inside a math-mode material (such as an equation environment).
